# how to use subplot within two loops

Tags: matlab

I need one figure with multiple graphs within two loops.

```matlab
for i=1:length(state)

   [block]

   for j=1:length(channel)

   [block]

   subplot(length(state),length(channel)),j)

   plot(a,b)% a and b are arrays of doubles.

   end

end
```

I want one figure with `size =length(state)*length(channel);` for instance I need all the graphs of state(1)within all channels in the first row etc...

But what I get is multiple figures (the length of state).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand well enough here is a way to do it :

```matlab
figure()
lx = 2;
ly = 3;
for ii = 1:lx
    for jj = 1:ly
        subplot(lx,ly,ly*(ii-1)+jj)
        plot(ii,jj,'o')
    end
end
```

#### Why `ly*(ii-1)+jj`?

The syntax of `subplot` is the following : `subplot(nbRows,nbCols,position)` and the position is given by an unique index going over all available subplots (see image) which is `ly*(ii-1)+jj`.

[image]